# do the cross-sum correctly

Tags: java

**So im trying to do cross-sums: 321=6 because 3+2+1=6 however ive run into a problem that i can locate with my code and was hoping if anyone else could help me to locate it**

```
import java.util.*;
public class Thewierdo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner Tinput = new Scanner (System.in);
     System.out.print("input number for cross-sum examination: ");
Double Tin = Tinput.nextDouble();
int m = 0;
if (Tin.isNaN()){
System.out.print("actual whole number please: ");
Tin = Tinput.nextDouble();
    }else{
        int cool = Tin.intValue();
        String gotcha= String.valueOf(cool);
int heads = gotcha.length();

while(heads >= 0){
    System.out.println(gotcha.charAt(1));
    char Tails=gotcha.charAt(heads);
    int finald = Character.getNumericValue(Tails);


    heads=heads-1;
 m += finald;
//made by Christian Risom
}
System.out.print(m);    
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: A debugger will help you locate it. SO is not a debugger.

Comment: why have u complicated it so much? Take the integer as input, keep dividing it by 10 until u get the remainder as 0. Add the digits at each step.

Comment: Here is what you do: delete the entire class and rewrite it. Before you write it, write some pseudo code for the problem and then double check it to make sure that it makes sense. After you believe the pseudo code makes sense, then you may try to implement it in code. If you run into any problems with your new code, your first thought should **NOT** be to ask on here, but to try and fix it on your own first.

Comment: The code doesn't even compile.  I suggest you go through each line in your IDE and fix the code so it compiles.  I would also try to simplify the code, you don't need half of it.

Answer (score 2):

That's my solution, i'm sure you could make it more simple, but there you go:

```
public static int cross_sums(int input) {
    int output = 0;
    do {
        output += input % 10;
        input /= 10;
    } while (input > 0);

    if (output > 9) {
        output = cross_sums(output);
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: This method does more than needed. With `if (output > 9) {output = cross_sums(output);}` it calculates the cross sum of the cross sum recursively. The first 6 lines of code are enough to calculate the cross sum (once). :-)

Answer (score 0):

The way you are checking if it is a valid number doesn't work. An error will be thrown on Tinput.nextDouble() if the input can't be interpreted as a double.

As others are saying, read your errors and debug. You likely have other problems as well.

Comment: This seems more like a comment, as it isn't really an answer.

Comment: I guess you're right. I'm pretty new to providing answers on SO, I'll keep that in mind moving forward.